# How to add dynamic placeholder to a SXA Rendering Variant?

Tags: sxa

Is there any way for me to add placeholders programatically inside the SXA rendering variant. I have tried using the `*` at the end of the name of placeholders but I keep getting some weird errors and the whole site just crashes.

Here is what I mean by this:

```
const string key = "carousel-1-*"
@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder(key)
```

I keep getting erros when I use this. Also, the model is `VariantListsRenderingModel`

Comment: Have you tried `@Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("key")`?

Comment: @Ashish I have not tried that. But I will try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of placeholder, just need to DynamicPlaceholder like below -

```
@Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("key")
```

No need to give `*`, this DynamicPlaceholder will manage a unique by itself like below -

[image]